# convert String to AnyObject in swift

Tags: swift, casting

I have a static string variable

```
struct numb {

    static var selectedNumber: String = String()

}
```

I am trying to unwrap ( while casting it as `AnyObject`) the value and assign it to `messageComposeViewController`

```
 if let textMessageRecipients :AnyObject  =  numb.selectedNumber 
    {
     messageComposeVC.recipients = textMessageRecipients as? [AnyObject]
    messageComposeVC.body = "Testing 123!"
    }
```

the compiler is throwing an error

```
bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type
```

How do I convert my `string` to `AnyObject` and assign it to the message view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your examples and the error you see, you are attempting to unwrap a value that isn't optional. You don't need to use `if let` when there is a value. You can force a cast using `if let` like this:

```
if let myValue:AnyObject = numb.selectedNumber as? AnyObject
```

This will produce a warning saying that casting a `String` to `AnyObject` will always succeed, again you don't need the `if let`, your casts will always succeed.

Your final example should look something like:

```
messageComposeVC.recipients = [numb.selectedNumber] as [AnyObject]
messageComposeVC.body = "Testing 123!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your `selectedNumber` to optional like this:

```
struct numb {

    static var selectedNumber: String?

}
```

Comment: Oh I totally missed that Thanks!.  but now for some strange reason the messageComposeVC.recipients has no value even though when I do a println there is a string value in textMessageRecipients. Any clue?

Comment: Yes because your `textMessageRecipients ` is `AnyObject` not `[AnyObject]` and you are assigning `textMessageRecipients ` as? `[AnyObject]` so it will return nil.

Answer (score 1):

Tested in Swift 2.1, Xcode 7. works !

```
var myItems : String?

myItems = ItemsTextfield.text

myItems as! AnyObject
```